# facebook test user fails on permissions

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, permissions

I am at a loss as to how to proceed. I have done so much reading but cannot solve what I thought would be relatively simple.

Scenario: I have a content management system which requires users to be subscribed and logged-in in order to use the following Facebook link:

The Facebook link(php, not using the FB SDK) is designed to allow content from a user’s FB Page to be accessed from the CMS.  The linking application initially requests a code from FB by submitting a client_id , scope and redirect_url  on the /dialog/oauth call,  then uses the returned ‘code’ parameter to go through an authentication process with FB graph api (the call is  /oauth/access_token ) to authenticate the logged-in user as having a FB Page,  and returns an access token. The access token is then used within api calls /v.2.10/{page-id} and /v2.10/ {page-id}/feed to return data about the Page owner and the Page content/posts/images.

I have created a Test App using the FB developer tool which will be submitted for review. Under Roles, I am the Admin, and I have added a Developer account. I have also added a Test User using the developer environment’s Roles >> Test Users option.

I have changed the password for the Test User, and have been able to log-in to the Test User FB account.

When I initiate the link to FB, the initial ‘code’ is returned by FB and the access token is then returned. The  Admin and Developer’s FB account details are ultimately accepted during authentication, and the link is established.

However, when I try to use the Test User’s account to establish the link, I get a permissions error.:- “Unsupported get request. Object with ID 'PAGENAME' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions or does not support this operation”.  I cannot see how I change the Test User’s permissions(or even if that is the real problem).

I notice that the Test User has an access token generated by FB when the Test User account is created. I’m guessing that this access token does not represent the correct permissions, but is used during the authentication process, thereby making the link fail.  I don’t know how to change the Test User’s permissions. Can it be done?

I have successfully logged into FB as the Test User, but can see no options to make changes to permissions, and have also tried using the Graph Explorer tool to alter permissions, but to no effect.

I have tried various scopes, and also no scope in the initial /dialog/oauth call. Nothing makes any difference to the Test User’s failure.

I presume my app submission to FB will fail if the reviewer uses the Test User account to authenticate the link, and it fails??? However, if the app reviewers used the Admin Account or the Developer Account, the link would succeed.

I’m at a loss as to how to resolve this. The FB documentation is not helping. What am I not understanding about this process?

Comment: Test users can not interact with “real” pages, simple as that. They only have access to pages created by them themselves in the first place. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-users#rules: _“Test users can't Like or Follow public Facebook Pages or post on their Timeline.”_

Comment: Thank you CBroe. Good spot. The FB docs became a blur of frustration yesterday.  I guess my options are therefore a) Create a test user Page and test the link, or b) ask FB reviewer to test the link from a 'real' account.